# Function not working inside a DeclareDocumentCommand

Tags: expl3, programming

Egreg's fantastic answer to the question [Execute a macro given in a key-value in expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361402/2483) is not working when integrated in previous code. 
The **This is my title** appears in the test, but it is not transformed.

The package (`docvar.sty`) until now looks like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{docvar}
    [2017/02/16 v1.00 Define, manage and use document variables.]
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_docvar_defined_prop
\prop_new:N \g_docvar_values_prop
\prop_new:N \g_docvar_inheritance_prop
\prop_new:N \g_docvar_transform_prop
\tl_new:N \l_docvar_transformation_tl
\tl_new:N \l_docvar_temp_tl
\DeclareDocumentCommand \definedocvar {o m} {
      \IfNoValueF { #1 }
      {
        \docvar_definition_properties:n {#1} {#2}
      }
     \prop_gput_if_new:Nnn \g_docvar_defined_prop {#2} {}
  }
       \tl_new:N \l_docvar_inherit_tl
       \keys_define:nn { docvar/define }
       {
         inherit .tl_set:N = \l_docvar_inherit_tl,
       }
       \cs_new_protected:Npn \docvar_definition_properties:n #1 #2
       {
         \group_begin:
         \keys_set:nn { docvar/define } { #1 }
         \tl_if_empty:NF \l_docvar_inherit_tl
           {
             \prop_gput:NnV \g_docvar_inheritance_prop {#2} \l_docvar_inherit_tl
           }
         \group_end:
         }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \docvar_key_defined:n #1 {p, T, F, TF}
  {
    \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_docvar_defined_prop {#1} {\prg_return_true:} {\prg_return_false:}
  }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \setdocvar {m m}{
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_docvar_values_prop {#1} {#2}
  }
       \keys_define:nn { docvar/get }
       {
         transform .tl_set:N = \l_docvar_tranformation_tl,
         transform .initial:n = \use:n,
       }
       \cs_new_protected:Npn \docvar_get_properties:n #1
       {
          \keys_set:nn { docvar/get } { #1 }
          }

  \cs_new_protected:Nx \__docvar_transform:nn
  {
    \typeout{in~transfrom}
    \tl_show:N \l_docvar_temp_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_docvar_temp_tl {#1{#2}}
    \tl_show:N \l_docvar_temp_tl
    \typeout{out~transfrom}
  }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__docvar_transform:nn { VV }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \getdocvar {o m}{
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueF { #1 }
  {
    \docvar_get_properties:n {#1}
    \tl_show:N \l_docvar_tranformation_tl
  }
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_docvar_values_prop {#2}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \g_tmpb_tl {#2}
  }
  {
    \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_docvar_inheritance_prop {#2}
    {
      \prop_get:NnN \g_docvar_inheritance_prop {#2} \g_tmpb_tl
    }
    {
      %TODO print message or empty value
    }
  }
  \prop_get:NVN \g_docvar_values_prop \g_tmpb_tl \g_tmpa_tl
  \tl_show:N \g_tmpa_tl
  \__docvar_transform:VV \l_docvar_transformation_tl \g_tmpa_tl
 \tl_use:N \l_docvar_temp_tl
  \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

And a test file `testminimal.lvt`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\input{regression-test}
\usepackage{docvar}
\begin{document}
\START
\definedocvar{title}

\setdocvar{title}{This is the long title}

Using a docvar directly:

\getdocvar{title}

Using a docvar that is inhereting:

\definedocvar[inherit=title]{subtitle}

\getdocvar{subtitle}

dovar retrieved with tranformation

\getdocvar[transform=\MakeUppercase]{title}

\showoutput
\end{document}
```

I can not make sense why it is not working.

Comment: And what is inside `regression-test`? Most likely you're running into expansion due to  `\DeclareDocumentCommand`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `regression-test` is a standard file: it's part of `l3build`

Comment: At least `\cs_new_protected:Nx \__docvar_transform:nn` should be `\cs_new_protected:Nn \__docvar_transform:nn`

Comment: I was under the impression that `\IfNoValueTF` was part of Expl3, but `\IfNoValueF` was a different command pertaining to the xtheorem package. Is this my misunderstanding, or is it related to the question?

Comment: @RobtA Both are provided by `xparse`.

Comment: @RobtA Standard LaTeX3 convention: `\IfNoValue(TF)` => `\IfNoValueT`, `\IfNoValueF` and `\IfNoValueTF` all exist and are provided in the same place.

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug such uncommented code.

Comment: As @egreg says, a bit tricky to follow as it stands. The obvious issue is that you have `\l_docvar_transformation_tl` in some places and `\l_docvar_tranformation_tl` in others: a simple typo!

Comment: @JosephWright: The typos was the culprit. Thanks, I was reading the text for a long time. Sorry for the poor comments. I had the package in dtx format, but I paste from the derived .sty file. Next time I will paste directly from the dtx.

Comment: @TeXtnik On that basis I'll probably close: a typo normally makes the question 'off topic'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the failure was caused by a simple typo.

Comment: @JosephWright I completely agree.